# Rounded inside border-radius in css without nested divs

Tags: html, css

I want to set rounded inside border `border-radius` ,(not outer `border-radius`) to my element without nested div's.

My idea is like this picture:

[image]

html source on 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmXDv/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    #s{
        width:200px;
        height: 200px;
        border:8px solid green ;
        border-radius:8px;
        background-color: red;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="s" >

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible in css3?

Comment: it's not possible on my application !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can but it won't be usable I presume, since there is `z-index: -1;` once there is another background it will go behind it...

```
#s {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius:8px;
    background-color: red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#s:before {
    content:'';
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    width: 216px;
    height: 216px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pmXDv/6/)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to fake this with a couple of extra properties being `outline` and `box-shadow`.

**[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxboL)**

**CSS**

```
#s{
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius:8px;
  background-color: red;
  margin:0 auto;
  outline:8px solid green;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 8px green;
}
```

NB. The `outline` by itself will leave a gap where the rounded corners are. The `box-shadow` merely fills in the gap.